# How I install Blender 2.62_freestyle on ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: blender

How do I install blender 2.62_freestyle on ubuntu 11.10. This is a specific build of blender from the Graphicall.org website.

Comment: Did you install it?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is download it, and as far as i remember you don't install, just unzip. 
To make a shortcut for it put the following:

```
    [Desktop Entry]
    Version=x.y
    Name=ProgramName
    Comment=This is my comment
    Exec=/home/***/Documents/exec.sh
    Icon=/home/***/Pictures/icon.png
    Terminal=false
    Type=Application
    Categories=Utility;Application;
```

in a text file obviously changing it for your program. The Exec path must be set for the location of the file "blender" in the folder you extracted. Name it as blender.desktop and go to "properties" in the context menu and in the "permissions" tab check "allow executing as program". Then search for this file in the dash and drag it to the launcher. that is how I did it. (-:

Answer (score 0):

According to the downloaded file:

Installation

Windows: The download .zip contains a Blender folder. You may put this anywhere on your hard drive. To launch Blender, double-click on Blender.exe.

**Linux, FreeBSD: Unpack the archive, Then run the Blender executable.**

Mac OS X: The downloaded package includes blender.app. Optionally copy this to your Applications folder, and add it to the dock by dragging it from there to the dock.

Installing Addons (all systems) Addons can be installed from the user preferences addons section, download an addon as a .py or .zip file, then press the "Install Addon" button and select the file to install it.